# Plant animation export but leaves don't follow stem

Tags: animation, export, unity

I'm trying to make an animation of a growing plant, so I followed this [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1QG1FOvPk8&ab_channel=PolygonRunway).

Everything works fine except for the export. I tried to export the entire model with animation to .fbx format and import it into Unity. However, the leaves do not follow the animation of the stem.

[image: Broken animation]

Any ideas how to fix it? Here is the [Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bf7ejdmtp61pjvz/tree1.blend?dl=0)

Comment: did you apply scale `Ctrl+A` > Scale. Also try exporting as Alembic

Comment: Most common exchange format support only armature and shapekeys deformations. All The rest Definitely needs formats like Alembic, but be aware Unity can't support alembic when building for android.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie thanks for the tip! I tried to apply Ctrl+A and export as abc. It looks better, but there are still some problems: the stem disappears when exporting to Unity, and one of the leaves doesn't follow the parent for some reason:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymh2gqceufdm034/plantupd.gif?dl=0)

I'm new to Blender, so maybe I'm missing something basic. Here are my blend (before applying Ctrl+A) and abc files:
[blender](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bf7ejdmtp61pjvz/tree1.blend?dl=0)
[abc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4j0n8zxrr9riwmo/tree1_5.abc?dl=0)

Comment: @L0Lock I see, thanks for the warning about android build! Then does it mean I should make a whole new animation using armature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender modifiers are specific to Blender only and may not be supported in other 3D applications. You can export as Alembic (.abc) and make sure you tick  *Flatten Hierarchy*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now it works!